# How to extract node data from XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract a node (called identifierValue) from this [XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17PlwLwW_n9w_c630xCTu9nAT6KErie2r/view?usp=sharing)

Couple of things that I tried:

```
$NewXML = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$ABN = $NewXML->xpath('//ABRPayloadSearchResults/response/searchResultsList/searchResultsRecord/ABN/identifierValue');
```

And

```
$ABN = $NewXML->ABRPayloadSearchResults[0]->response->searchResultsList->searchResultsRecord->ABN->identifierValue;
```

but not getting any results. I tried the same methods with a simple dummy XML and it works.

Any idea why this is failing for my XML?

Comment: Please see this post about how to post a minimal reproducible example: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example> It's not possible for someone to replicate your problem, because your sample code is incomplete. Most likely, though, your problem is that the elements in your XML file are in a namespace whose URI is <http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/literalTypes>, but your XPath assumes they have no namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your problem is that your XPath query uses element names which are not in a namespace, whereas the elements in your XML *are* in a namespace.

If you associate a prefix (e.g. "abr") with the namespace URI used in the XML (i.e. http://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearchRPC/literalTypes) using the function described here https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php, then you should be able to query with an XPath expression that uses that prefix, e.g.

```xml
//abr:ABRPayloadSearchResults/abr:response/abr:searchResultsList/abr:searchResultsRecord/abr:ABN/abr:identifierValue
```